# Faster Algorithm for the isomorphism of graphs of certain types

Tags: algorithms

Let $G = (V_1,E_1)$ and $H=(V_2,E_2)$ are two graphs. It is given that $l_1$ many edges (known to us) of $G$ will map to $l_1$ edges of $H$ in any isomorphism of $G$ and $H$. If I remove $l_1$ edges of $G$ (keeping the end vertices) then new graph is $G'$ and graph obtained after removing $l_1$ edges (keeping the end vertices) from $H$ is $H'$. It is given that isomorphism of $G'$ and $H'$ can be performed in polynomial time (say p). The algorithm to solve the isomorphism of $G$ and $H$ will take $O(l_1! p)$. Is it possible to solve the isomorphism of $G$ and $H$ in faster than $O(l_1! p)$

Comment: What are your thoughts?  What kinds of examples have you considered?  In general there are many algorithms for solving graph isomorphism on $n$ vertices faster than $n!$ time; I am wondering whether you're really asking the question that you want answered.

Comment: @ D.W. I think it should be doable in $O(2^l) \times p$ time as I have seen many algorithms with this runtime like bounded color classes isomorphism etc but I am not able to see how to do it.

Comment: There seems to be a corner case where $l_1=|E_1|$? Therefore you can't be quicker than the best isomorphism algorithm.

Comment: @ Albert Hendriks i don't think so see the babai's quasipolynomail time algorithm.

Comment: I'm not getting something here, doesn't the resulting isomorphism of the graphs G', H' (the o/p of the polynomial time algorithm) imposes a certain order of the vertices? i.e., u r not free to try the $ l1! $ choices; u may even get a contradiction?